# Gluon app won't start on iOS

Tags: java, javafx, robovm, gluon, gluon-mobile

And Google is not really helpful.

```
Mar 20, 2016 9:00:13 AM com.gluonhq.charm.down.common.PlatformFactory getPlatform
SEVERE: null
Throwable occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.down.ios.IOSPlatform
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findClassInClasspathForLoader(Native Method)
    at java.lang.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
QuantumRenderer: shutdown
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.down.common.PlatformFactory.getPlatform(PlatformFactory.java)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.ios.BasicLauncher.main(BasicLauncher.java)

Exception in Application start method

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method)
    at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java)
    at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.ios.BasicLauncher.main(BasicLauncher.java)
```

This is the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.linguica.gradle:maven-settings-plugin:0.5'
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.7'
    }
}

plugins {
  id "net.linguica.maven-settings" version "0.5" // make maven settings.xml available in gradle (and automatically setup the security settings for the repos based on the grable name vs maven id
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

configurations {
    provided
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/' }
    jcenter() 
    maven { url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/' }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('nl.knowledgeplaza:DH2RIAShared:1.55-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude module: 'hessian'
    }
    compile 'blog.monkeyboy:hessian-android:1.0'

    compile 'org.jfxtras:jfxtras-controls:8.0-r5-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.miglayout:miglayout-javafx:5.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx:8.9-retrolambda'

    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'

    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.1.0'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.1.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:2.1.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:2.1.0'
}

mainClassName = 'nl.softworks.dh2.dh2fx.DH2FX'

retrolambda {
    defaultMethods true
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        packagingOptions {
           pickFirst  'roboto/Apache License.txt'
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize = '1024m'
        }
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file? How do you deploy your app?

Comment: This is the deploy onto the simulator: gradlew launchIOSDevice --info

Comment: I've added the build.gradle to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying on iOS, you need to use the `forceLinkClasses` [command](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.1.0/#_ios_2), so RoboVM can link in the classes contained in those packages during compilation.

You will need to include the classes on your package, and those on any third dependency you may use:

```
jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'nl.softwork.**.*', 
                             'com.gluonhq.**.*', 
                             'org.jfxtras.**.*',
                             ...  ]
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is interesting, though. I would have found that, if not for that the gradle.build was from Gluon's HelloWorld example project, and I had expected that it would have been setup correctly for all Gluon packages (it included the gluon dependencies).

Comment: Actually, the HelloWorld sample doesn't require any extra class linked. If you create a Gluon Mobile project using Gluon IDE [plugins](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.1.0/#netbeans-plugin), you will see that the created project includes the required linked classes.

Comment: I used a HelloWorld example I download (not created by the IDE). Probably an older version then.